# failed using scanf to read from pipe

Tags: pipe, c, exec, ipc

Working on IPC I was asked to write a C program that works as pipe between other two C executables:

The first executable named 'sln1.out' receive six arguments and print three numbers.

The second executable named 'sln2.out' receive three arguments and print one number.

I devided the following code to two parts - the first is the write to the pipe and as much as I know it works. The problem start in the second part: I closed the `stdin` so now when I use `dup(fd[0])` the new file descriptor duplicate shall be allocated where the `stdin` was, and I suppose I can use `scanf` to read from the pipe under those circumstances - But for some reason it didn't work

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // check number of arguments.
    if(argc != 7)
    {
            printf("Wrong parameters");
            exit(1);
    }

    // creating the pipe.
    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);

/* PART ONE: forking a child for 'sln1.out' that writes to fd[1] */

    // I  want to fork this process, and change the image of the child process to the 'sln1.out' process.
    pid_t pid_sln1 = fork();
    int sln1_status;
    if (pid_sln1 < 0)
    {
            perror("fork error, sln1");
    }
    else if(pid_sln1 == 0)
    {
            char* const parmListSln1[] = {"./sln1.out",argv[1],argv[2],argv[3],
                                            argv[4],argv[5],argv[6],NULL};
            // i closed the stdout, and used 'dup' that return the file descriptor
            //  of stdout as duplicate of fd[1]!
            close(STDOUT_FILENO);
            dup(fd[1]);

            execv("./sln1.out",parmListSln1);
            printf("Return not expected, exacv error.\n");
            exit(1);
    }

    // wait untill the child process terminated.
    wait(&sln1_status);
    if(sln1_status == 0)
    {
            printf("child process terminated successfully\n");
            // if we want to read from fd[0] we must close the write to fd[1]

            close(fd[1]);
    }
    else
    {
            printf("child process failed\n");
            exit(1);
    }


/* PART TWO: forking a child for 'sln2.out' that reads from fd[0] */

    // The same idea - forking a child to change its image to the 'sln2.out' process.
    pid_t pid_sln2 = fork();
    int sln2_status;

    if(pid_sln2 < 0)
    {
            printf("fork error, sln2.\n");
            exit(1);
    }
    else if(pid_sln2 == 0)
    {
            // closing 'stdin' and the use fo 'dup' create a duplicate to the readable
            // side of the pipe where the standard input should be
            close(STDIN_FILENO);
            dup(fd[0]);

            // reading the input from the pipe - with the same method used to 'stdin'!
            char* in[3];
            scanf("%s %s %s",in[0],in[1],in[2]);
            // build the parameters list for 'sln2.out'
            char* const paramListSln2[] = { "./sln2.out", in[0], in[1], in[2], NULL };

            // execute 'sln2.out'
            execv("./sln2.out",paramListSln2);
            printf("Return not expexted, execv error");
            exit(1);

    }

    // wait untill the child process terminated and determine success.
    wait(&sln2_status);
    if (sln2_status == 0)
    {
            printf("2nd child process terminated successfully!\n");
            exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
            printf("error with 'sln2.out' child process.\n");
            exit(1);
    }

    exit(0);
}
```

The output I get can give some more details:

```
child process terminated successfully
error with 'sln2.out' child process.
```

I'm pretty sure the problem with the `sln2.out` process is because the failure of `scanf` since I tried to print the scanned arguments and it also failed...

Comment: If you are writing all 3 executable, sln1, sln2, and the wrapper shown above, and they are tightly integrated. Then it may be better to put them into one executable (no exec). I also note that you wait for 1 to finish before starting 2, this will cause problems if the pipe fills.

Comment: First I'm writing all three programs, but I have to keep this structure since that what the college demands...
I can't see a real reason that the pipe will filled, if I got this right the pipe can hold up to 4KB right? and the inputs/outputs here are very small.

Comment: Yes, pipes can hold more than 4 KiB, but filling a pipe is a problem in 'the real world' (outside university exercises).  Keep that in mind.  What diagnostics have you put in the two executables?  Do you print the argument lists etc to `stderr`?  Do you print whatever number they generate to `stderr` as well?  When things are not going according to plan (as now, given that you're asking the question), then careful diagnostic output tracking which process is generating what output etc becomes crucial (or, if not crucial, very helpful).  Also ensure you test every system call to ensure it works.

Comment: You print error messages to `stdout` instead of `stderr`, and you don't terminate them with newlines.  Both are important!  The mantra is "error messages go to standard error".  It's easy, and obvious.  Error messages go to `stderr`!

Comment: Is `sln1.out` more complex than `int main(int argc, char **argv) { if (argc != 7) { fprintf(stderr, "%s: incorrect argument count %d\n", argv[1], argc); exit(1); } printf("1 2 3\n"); return 0; }` — or, at least, is that an adequate surrogate?  And `sln2.out` would be similar: `int main(int argc, char **argv) { if (argc != 4) { fprintf(stderr, "%s: incorrect argument count %d\n", argv[1], argc); exit(1); } printf("321\n"); return 0; }`?  These meet the specifications given.  (Obviously, they'd need headers `<stdio.h>` and `<stdlib.h>`, though they could easily be revised to avoid the latter.)

Comment: The consecutive lines `char* in[3]; scanf("%s %s %s",in[0],in[1],in[2]);` are a source of crashes — the pointers don't point anywhere.  You need to allocate storage for the pointers to point at, or use the `m` modifier to `%s` and other consequential changes so that `scanf()` allocates the memory for you.  Note that some systems (e.g. macOS) do not support the POSIX-mandated [`sscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sscanf.html) modifier. Using `char in[3][50];` is probably easiest (though you should use `%49s` each time in the `scanf()` format string.)

Comment: so you saing all this headache is just because I dropped `malloc`? what a nightmare

Comment: You aren't closing enough file descriptors in the child. **Rule of thumb**: If you [`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html) one end of a pipe to standard input or standard output, close both of the original file descriptors from `pipe()` as soon as possible. In particular, that means before using any of the [`exec*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html) family of functions. The rule also applies with either `dup()` or [`fcntl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html) with `F_DUPFD`.

Comment: I don't know that it is the only problem; it is one problem that my compiler told me about as I tried to compile your code.  I called your program `ctrl61.c` and (tried to) compile with: `gcc -O3   -g      -std=c11   -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes         ctrl61.c -o ctrl61` — and the compiler refused to compile it.

Comment: Thanks so much for all your excellent advices. I will try to be more persistent about error messages to `perror`, maybe its another cause of the crash here. the templates you suggested for `sln1.out` and `sln2.out` are matching more and less the executables.

Comment: interesting, my gcc compiled it without warnings... not to mention errors. is this because the `-std=c11` feature?

Comment: You aren't closing enough file descriptors in the child. **Rule of thumb**: If you [`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html) one end of a pipe to standard input or standard output, close both of the original file descriptors from `pipe()` as soon as possible. In particular, that means before using any of the [`exec*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html) family of functions. The rule also applies with either `dup()` or [`fcntl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html) with `F_DUPFD`.

Comment: In this program, it may not matter, but if you are working with pipes more generally, it is often crucial to make sure you close all the unused pipes, as processes may not get EOF when they need to.  Personally, I don't like `perror()` for reporting errors; its formatting isn't powerful enough.  However, it is better than some alternatives. I use the code available in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as files `stderr.c` and `stderr.h` in the [src/libsoq](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq) sub-directory.

Comment: I'm using GCC 8.2.0 with those compilation options; it gave me the warning: `ctrl61.c:78:13: error: ‘in[0]’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Werror=maybe-uninitialized]` (and similarly for `in[1]` and `in[2]`.  GCC has gotten better with warnings.  If you're using a GCC 4.x version, you'll get fewer and less informative warnings — they've done excellent work on improving them in releases 5 through 8 (starting with 5).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184966/discussion-between-z-e-nir-and-jonathan-leffler).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Primary problem — uninitialized pointers

When I compiled the code in the question (source file, `ctrl61.c`) using the command line:

```
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes ctrl61.c -o ctrl61
```

(with GCC 8.2.0 running on a Mac with macOS 10.14.2 Mojave), I got warnings like:

```
ctrl61.c:78:13: error: ‘in[0]’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Werror=maybe-uninitialized]
```

for each of `in[0]`, `in[1]` and `in[2]`, and the line identified was the call to `scanf()`.  Uninitialized pointers are a source of crashes and, indeed, inspecting the code shows that the pointers are not initialized.
You need to allocate storage for the pointers to point at.  The simplest change is to use:

```
char in[3][50];
```

(though you should then use %49s each time in the `scanf()` format string.)
Or you could use the `m` modifier to `%s` and other consequential changes so that `scanf()` allocates the memory for you. Note that some systems (e.g. macOS) do not support the POSIX-mandated [`sscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sscanf.html) modifier.

You aren't closing enough file descriptors in the child (or, indeed, in the parent).

**Rule of thumb**: If you
[`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html)
one end of a pipe to standard input or standard output, close both of the
original file descriptors returned by
[`pipe()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pipe.html)
as soon as possible.
In particular, you should close them before using any of the
[`exec*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html)
family of functions.

The rule also applies if you duplicate the descriptors with either
[`dup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup.html)
or
[`fcntl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html)
with `F_DUPFD.

In this program, it may not matter, but if you are working with pipes more generally, it is often crucial to make sure you close all the unused pipes, as processes may not get EOF when they need to.

#### Error reporting

In comments, you mentioned using `perror()` to report problems. Personally, I don't like `perror()` for reporting errors; its formatting isn't powerful enough. However, it is better than some alternatives.

I usually use some code that is available in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as files `stderr.c` and `stderr.h` in the [src/libsoq](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq) sub-directory.  This has extensive control over the formatting.

There is a conceptually similar package, [`err(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/err.3.html) available on Linux and BSD (including macOS).  I prefer mine, simply because it is mine (and because it has more powerful controls than the `err(3)` package).

#### Control code `ctrl61.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 7)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5 arg6\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);

    pid_t pid_sln1 = fork();
    int sln1_status;
    if (pid_sln1 < 0)
    {
        perror("fork error, sln1");
    }
    else if (pid_sln1 == 0)
    {
        char *paramListSln1[] =
        {
            "./sln1.out", argv[1], argv[2], argv[3],
            argv[4], argv[5], argv[6], NULL
        };

        close(STDOUT_FILENO);
        dup(fd[1]);
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);

        execv(paramListSln1[0], paramListSln1);
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to exec %s\n", argv[0], paramListSln1[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    pid_t pid_sln2 = fork();
    int sln2_status;

    if (pid_sln2 < 0)
    {
        printf("fork error, sln2.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if (pid_sln2 == 0)
    {
        close(STDIN_FILENO);
        dup(fd[0]);
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);

        char in[3][50];
        scanf("%49s %49s %49s", in[0], in[1], in[2]);

        char *const paramListSln2[] = { "./sln2.out", in[0], in[1], in[2], NULL };

        execv(paramListSln2[0], paramListSln2);
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to exec %s\n", argv[0], paramListSln2[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    close(fd[0]);
    close(fd[1]);

    int pid1 = wait(&sln1_status);
    if (sln1_status == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "child process %d terminated successfully\n", pid1);
        close(fd[1]);
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "child process %d failed 0x%.4X\n", pid1, sln1_status);
        exit(1);
    }

    int pid2 = wait(&sln2_status);
    if (sln2_status == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "child process %d terminated successfully\n", pid2);
        close(fd[1]);
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "child process %d failed 0x%.4X\n", pid2, sln2_status);
        exit(1);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

There are stark repetitions in this code that should be fixed by writing functions.

Note that this version launches both programs before waiting for either to exit.

#### Auxilliary program `sln1.out.c`

This is closely based on the code hypothesized in a comment but fixes a bug where the comment used `argv[1]` but should have used `argv[0]`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static inline void dump_args(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int argnum = 0;
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: %d arguments\n", argv[0], argc);
    while (*argv != 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "%d: [%s]\n", argnum++, *argv++);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    dump_args(argc, argv);
    if (argc != 7)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: incorrect argument count %d\n", argv[0], argc);
        return(1);
    }
    printf("1 2 3\n");
    return(0);
}
```

The program `sln2.out.c` differs in requiring 3 arguments and printing `321` instead of `1 2 3`.

#### Example run

```
$ ./ctrl61 abc zoo def pqr tuv 999
./sln1.out: 7 arguments
0: [./sln1.out]
1: [abc]
2: [zoo]
3: [def]
4: [pqr]
5: [tuv]
6: [999]
child process 15443 terminated successfully
./sln2.out: 4 arguments
0: [./sln2.out]
1: [1]
2: [2]
3: [3]
321
child process 15444 terminated successfully
$
```

This shows that `sln2.out` was passed three arguments read from the standard output of `sln1.out`.